# Translation of "we", pronoun in official company introduction material

Tags: translation, pronouns

I am translating a document that looks like an official introduction of a company maybe to be placed on their website or marketing material.

In the document, the first sentence starts with the name of the company, then later on they refer to the company as "we", ex. We are a strong competitor in used equipment market.

I personally think "We" is not appropriate on official marketing material, so is the direct translation 我们 and would like to change to 本公司 or even just use the name of the company in place of the pronoun.  Or since they are using "we", means it's not really written that seriously, it's ok to just translate as 我们？

What is the correct thing to do in this case?

Comment: I think `我们` is OK. `本公司` and the name of the company are a little formal and rigid, but `我们` is cordial.

Comment: Thank you, since all the answers I got so far said 我们 is ok, I think I will go with that :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer would be yes, you can use 我们 because it's the most formal way of saying 'we'.

Comment: @Tina Lin Your welcome.